# Python variables between files

Tags: python-3.x

```py
# file1.py
a = 1
print(a)
# 1
```

```py
# file2.py
from file1 import a
print(a)
# 0
```

I want "1" output in file2.py, why it doesn't work?

Comment: Are the 2 files in the same directory?

Comment: @bigbounty If it was in a different directory, error would be `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'file1'`

Comment: @RoshinRaphel OP didn't specify any errors

Comment: @bigbounty Yes that is true, my bad, I assumed that by `#0` he meant the output was `0`

Comment: I dont have any errors, in same directory

Comment: Can you give the directory structure of how the 2 files are present? @p1oXYZ

Comment: root:
      - file1.py
      - file2.py

Comment: is `file1.py` open in an editor and not saved?

Answer (score 1):

Your code should give the below output

`1`

`1`

You get two 1's in the output because when python imports a file it executes it. When file1 is imported, it's print statement is executed. The second 1 is from the print statement in the file2

**If you are getting 0 as output check if you have the permissions to execute these files (Since your files are in root directory)**